# $\sin(t)$ solution of $\ddot{x}=-x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\sin(t)$ be the solution of the differential equation $\ddot{x}=-x$.
Why is the general solution of $\ddot{x}=-x$, $x(t)=\lambda \sin(t) + \mu \cos(t)$, with $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are linear independent solutions (they form a fundemental system of solutions). The general solution is any linear combination of those solutions.

Comment: In particular, the general solution to a second order, linear, homogeneous differential equation is a linear combination of any two, independent solutions.  The phrase "Let sin(t) be the solution ..." is odd.  "sin(t)" **is** a solution so it isn't necessary to say "let".    On the other hand it is not **the** solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a solution of $x''=-x$. Then\begin{align}x''=-x&\iff x''+x=0\\&\implies x'x''+xx'=0\\&\iff2(x'x''+xx')=0\\&\iff\bigl((x')^2+x^2\bigr)'=0\\&\iff(x')^2+x^2\text{ is constant.}\end{align}So, if we assume that $x(0)=x'(0)=0$, the conclusion is that $x$ must be the null function.

Otherwise, let $y(t)=x(t)-x(0)\cos(t)-x'(0)\sin(t)$. Then

1. $y''=-y$;
2. $y(0)=0$;
3. $y'(0)=0$.

Therefore, $y\equiv0$, and this means that$$x(t)=x(0)\cos(t)+x'(0)\sin(t).$$

Answer (score 2):

Because also $\cos t$ is a solution of the same equation and, since $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are linearly independent solutions of a second order differential equation, the general solution is a linear combination:
$\lambda \sin t + \mu \cos t$

Answer (score 0):

Who says $\sin(t)$ is *the* solution of $\ddot x = -x$? 
It is *a* solution, not *the* solution.

You can see that the general solution confirms that $\sin(t)$ is *a* solution, because if you set $\lambda=1, \mu=0$ in the general solution,
the resulting function is $x(t) = \sin(t).$